# $[G:H]<\infty$. Show that there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $N \subset H$, $[G:N]<\infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I am reading "An Introduction to Algebraic Systems" by Kazuo Matsuzaka.(By the way, Kazuo Matsuzaka was one of the most famous elementary mathematics writers in Japan.)

There is the following problem in this book with many hints.
With the hints, I can solve this problem, but I want to know a typical solution for this problem.

p.78 Ex.9

> $G$ is a group.
>   $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
>   $[G:H]$ is finite.
>
> Show that there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $N \subset H$ and $[G:N]$ is finite.

I will write the hints and my answer:

p.65 Ex.12

> If $S \subset G$, then $N(S) = \{g \in G | g S = S g\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

p.65 Ex.13

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is a (normal) subgroup of $N(H) = \{g \in G | g H = H g\}$.

p.60 Ex.4(Hint: use Ex.2 and Ex.3 on p.60)

> If $H_1, \cdots, H_n$ are subgroups of a group $G$ and 
>   $[G:H_i] < \infty$ for all $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, 
>   then, $[G:H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n] < \infty$ and $[G:H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_n] \leq [G:H_1] \cdots [G:H_n]$.

p.77 Ex.6

> Let $G$ be a group.
>   Let $S$ be a subset of $G$.
>   Let $[G:N(S)] < \infty$.
>
> Then, $\#\{a S a^{-1} | a \in G\} = [G:N(S)]$.

p.77 Ex.8

> Let $G$ be a group.
>   Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.
>   Let $N = \bigcap_{a \in G} a H a^{-1}$.
>
> (1)
>   Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
>
> (2)
>   Show that if $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $M \subset H$, then, $M \subset N$.

And my solution using these hints is here:

> $[G:H] < \infty$ by assumption and $H$ is a subgroup of $N(H)$ by p.65 Ex.13.
>   Obviously $[G:N(H)] < \infty$ because $N(H)$ is larger than $H$.
>   By p.77 Ex.6, $\#\{a H a^{-1} | a \in G\} = [G:N(H)] =: n<\infty$.
>   Obviously $[G:H] = [G:a H a^{-1}]$ for all $a \in G$ because $H$ and $a H a^{-1}$ have the same algebraic structure in $G$.
>   Let $\{a H a^{-1} | a \in G\} = \{a_1 H a_1^{-1}, \cdots, a_n H a_n^{-1}\}$.
>   $[G:a_1 H a_1^{-1} \cap \cdots \cap a_n H a_n^{-1}] \leq [G:a_1 H a_1^{-1}] \cdots [G:a_n H a_n^{-1}] < \infty$ by p.60 Ex.4.
>   $N := a_1 H a_1^{-1} \cap \cdots \cap a_n H a_n^{-1}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$  by p.77 Ex.8. and $N \subset H$ and $[G:N] < \infty$.

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative proof, it would be best to include the proof (and hints) from the book.

Comment: @TheoBendit I will add the hints(huge hints) and my answer.

Comment: There is no solution for this problem in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ acts on $G/H$, this defines a morphism $G\rightarrow Sym(G/H)$ consider the kernel$N$  of this morphism.

Comment: I don't know "action" yet, so I will read about "action" in the above book soon. Thank you very much for one line proof, Tsemo Aristide.

Comment: Why is it that $[G:N]$ is finite? I understand it suffices to prove that $[H:N]$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ act on the cosets of $H$. That gives a homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ into $Sym(n)$ where $n = |G:H|$. Now let $N = ker(\phi)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for one line proof, user515430. I am sorry I didn't decide your answer as best answer because Tsemo Aristide answered earlier.(1 min).